# 4 input counter with display

Tags: counter, 24v

I have 4 switching sensors for all around detection, they output either 24V or 0V.
I want a counter that will add 1 everytime one of the sensors detects something (sometimes 3 of them will detect together), that means add 1 everytime states go from 0 to 24V. Then, I'll need 3 displays to display the result (but I guess 2 would be fine).
Is it possible without micro controllers? Too much hasle? Easy peasy?
Better off with 8051? Consider on the cheap.

Thank you!

Comment: if 8051 is cheap for you to program

Comment: a '4553 counter would have been a solution 20 years ago but these 3 digit counter chips (CD4553. MC14553 etc) are now no-longer available. :(

Comment: Too much hassle using discrete components. A simple arduino nano + I2C 4 digit display(s) should do the trick . Just ensure the input to the arduino is kept to an appropriate voltage.

Comment: Every dollar-store pedometer is a counter with display.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to use as displays. If just LEDs are sufficient to show the binary counts then you could use jk flipflops for up counting. JK FlipFlops are available in PDIP-16 packages such as SN74LS109AN IC which costs a dollar or two. Depending on the maximum counts required you could adjoin multiple flipflops to increase the counting bits.

[image: 4-bit Up Counter]

The Sensor inputs pin shown in the picture could be connected to your sensors with the resistor to separate the 24V and 0V outputs of the sensors. The resistance values will have to be high enough such that the maximum sensor output current is not reached.

Comment: thanks a lot. I was thinking about a 7 segment display, though this provides what I need in a simpler way.